# How do I get the space shuttle launch in Game Boy Tetris?

Tags: game-boy, tetris

I've been playing Tetris on the virtual Game Boy console on my Nintendo Switch. As a kid, with an actual Game Boy, I remember getting to see [a space shuttle launch](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jclop0AXA-4/maxresdefault.jpg) after doing well enough on an A-Type game.

[This Gamespot forum guide](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/gameboy/585960-tetris/faqs/8483) claims that this ending appears after you get more than 200,000 points. So far, I've managed about 269,000 points (getting to level 16), but I only saw [the third rocket in this image](http://www.kobash.com/tetris/theory/sextris_rockets.gif) launch.

The image states that the three rockets appear after 100,000, 150,000, and 200,000 points respectively, which matches my experience, but says nothing about the shuttle.

What do I have to do to get the shuttle?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are playing the wrong game mode.

In A-TYPE, a rocket launch is shown when the player surpasses a certain score:

- 100,000 to 149,999 points: small rocket
- 150,000 to 199,999 points: medium-sized rocket
- 200,000 or more points: big rocket

[image: The small, medium, and large Tetris rocket graphics]

In B-TYPE, a screen with Russian musicians and dancers is shown when completing 25 lines on level 9. The number of musicians and dancers increases with the initial height level. **When completing level 9 on height 5, a Buran shuttle launch is shown additionally**.

[image: The Tetris space shuttle graphic]

[Source](https://harddrop.com/wiki/Tetris_(Game_Boy))

Comment: Ah! Sweet. Are the A-Type vessels missiles, and not rockets?

Comment: Who knows, it's hard to tell from the sprites

Comment: This is the kind of misunderstanding that could spark a nuclear war! What is Nintendo thinking?!?

Comment: "Big missile" looks like a R-7 derivative. Initially an ICBM, the rocket family has been the primary orbital launch system for the Soviet Union and Russia. Here it appears to have a Soyuz spacecraft on top.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite In general - especially during the Space Race - the only difference between a missile and a rocket is whether you put explosives or a satellite/capsule on top.  To me the "medium-sized rocket" looks a lot like a [Titan II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_II_GLV) - the launch vehicle ("rocket") used for the Gemini program, which was derived from an ICBM (missile).

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle. Cool. Given that the A-type thingies seem to launch from the same location as the shuttle, and feature in the flagship puzzle game for a console aimed at children, maybe we can assume no explosives.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I think that's a fair assumption.  Additionally, while the tops of the Titan ICBM and Titan GLV look nearly identical at this resolution (a black triangle), the top of the R7 definitely shows a Soyuz-like capsule rather than its missile variant (which again would be a simple tapering triangle).